# Anylogic: How to create an objective function using values of two dataset (for optimization experiment)?

Tags: function, optimization, parameters, dataset, anylogic

In my Anylogic model I have a population of agents (4 terminals) were trucks arrive at, are being served and depart from. The terminals have two parameters (`numberOfGates` and `servicetime`) which influence the `departures` per hour of trucks leaving the terminals. Now I want to tune these two parameters, so that the amount of departures per hour is closest to reality (I know the actual departures per hour). I already have two datasets within each terminal agent, one with de amount of `departures` per hour that I simulate, and one with the `observedDepartures` from the data.

[image: Terminal agent]

I already compare these two datasets in plots for every terminal:

[image: Plot observed vs simulated]

Now I want to create an optimization experiment to tune the `numberOfGates` and `servicetime` of the terminals so that the `departure` dataset is the closest to the `observedDepartures` dataset. Does anyone know how to do create a(n) (objective) function for this optimization experiment the easiest way?

When I add a variable `diff` that is updated every hour by `abs( departures - observedDepartures)` and put `root.diff` in the optimization experiment, it gives me the `eq(null) is not allowed. Use isNull() instead` error, in a line that reads the database for the `observedDepartures` (see last picture), but it works when I run the simulation normally, it only gives this error when running the optimization experiment (I don't know why).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the absolute value of the sum of the differences for each replication. That is, create a variable that logs the `| difference |` for each hour, call it `diff`. Then in the optimization experiment, minimize the value of the sum of that variable. In fact this is close to a typical regression model's objectives. There they use a more complex objective function, by minimizing the sum of the square of the differences.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and help. I am not succeeding in making this work. How do I store the difference for each hour? Automatically when I give the variable the absolute difference between the variable/numbers that change every hour? Or by adding an cyclic event (but I don't succeed in adding some value from an event to a variable)? And how to sum this variable in the objective function? It now says that that variable cannot be resolved to a variable...

Comment: You actually need one figure for the whole replication which will be the sum of the absolute values of the deviations. And you should be able to update a variable from the event..at the end of each hour, you just update the `diff` variable with `diff+=abs( departures - observedDepartures)` . In the optimization experiment, you won't need to sum. Your objective function will be ` minimize (diff)`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with the first sentence. I added the event and variable in the terminal agent (so every terminal has one) and for the optimization experiment (which has top-level Terminal) minimized `diff`, but I got this error `eq(null) is not allowed. Use isNull() instead`. Maybe because I have 4 terminal agents? But not sure why..

Comment: Yes.. `root.terminals(0).diff + root.terminals(1).diff+...` in the objective function doesn't work?

Comment: No because the root level is already terminal (because in the terminal agent is the variable `diff` and the changing parameters `numberOfGates` and `serviceTime`). So that's why I have the objective function to minimize `root.diff`. But then it gives me the error that `eq(null) is not allowed`

Comment: can you please add a screenshot of your optimization experiment (especially the objective fn part).

Comment: I added a screenshot of the optimization experiment in my question

Comment: ahh I see now. root(0) or root.get(0) don't work?

Comment: No, unfortunately it says `The method root(int) is undefined for the type Optimization` and `The method get(int) is undefined for the type Terminal`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241859/discussion-between-yashar-ahmadov-and-ella).

Comment: When running the experiment in a smaller model with only the essentials for that part, it works :) thanks!

Comment: great! always happy to help :)

Comment: This solution is recreating what a Calibration experiment already does (in a more mathematically correct way) using the in-built `difference` function to calculate the 'area between two curves' (which is what the optimisation is trying to minimise). In your case it will need to be a sum of the differences between the empirical and simulated datasets for the 4 terminals (or possibly a weighted sum if the fit for some terminals is considered more important than for others).

Answer (score 0):

A Calibration experiment already does (in a more mathematically correct way) what you are trying to do, using the in-built `difference` function to calculate the 'area between two curves' (which is what the optimisation is trying to minimise). You don't need to calculate differences or anything yourself. (There are two variants of the function to compare either two Data Sets (your case) or a Data Set and a Table Function (useful if your empirical data is not at the same time points as your synthetic simulated data).)

In your case it (the objective function) will need to be a sum of the differences between the empirical and simulated datasets for the 4 terminals (or possibly a weighted sum if the fit for some terminals is considered more important than for others).

So your objective is something like

```
difference(root.terminals(0).departures, root.terminals(0).observedDepartures)
+ difference(root.terminals(1).departures, root.terminals(1).observedDepartures)
+ difference(root.terminals(2).departures, root.terminals(2).observedDepartures)
+ difference(root.terminals(3).departures, root.terminals(2).observedDepartures)
```

(It would be better to calculate this for an arbitrary population of terminals in a function but this is the 'raw shape' of the code.)

A Calibration experiment is actually just a wizard which creates an Optimization experiment set up in a particular way (with a UI and all settings/code already created for you), so you can just use that objective in your existing Optimization experiment (but it won't have a built-in useful UI like a Calibration experiment). This also means you can still set this up in the Personal Learning Edition too (which doesn't have the Calibration experiment).